# Python Pandas. Creating DataFrame with Series does not preserve dtype

Tags: python, pandas

I have a use-case which I thought would be quite common, and so I thought this question of mine should be easy to answer for myself, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere. Consider the following.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"id": numpy.random.choice(range(100), 5, replace=False),
                       "value": numpy.random.rand(5)})
df2 = pandas.DataFrame([df["id"], df["value"]*2]).T
```

Basically I'm creating a `DataFrame`, `df2`, based on the values of an old `DataFrame`, `df`. Now if we run

```
print(df.dtypes, end="\n------\n")
print(df2.dtypes)
```

we get

```
id         int64
value    float64
dtype: object
------
id       float64
value    float64
dtype: object
```

You can see that the `dtype` of the first column of `df2` is `float64`, instead of `int64` as it should be, even though the `dtype` of the `Series` itself is `int64`. This behaviour is very perplexing to me, and I can't believe that it's intentional. How do I create a `DataFrame` from some `Series`s and preserve the `dtype`s of the `Series`s? In my mind it should be as easy as `pandas.DataFrame([s1, s2], dtypes=[int, float])`, but you can't do that in `pandas` for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Columns* of a DataFrame always have a single dtype.  (This is because, under
the hood, Pandas stores *columns* of data which have the same dtype in blocks.)

When `pd.DataFrame` is passed a list of Series, it 
unpacks each Series into a separate row. Since the Series have different dtypes, the columns end up with values with mixed dtypes. Pandas tries to resolve this by upgrading all values in each column to a single dtype.

---

You could define `df2` with:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': df["id"], 'value': df["value"]*2})
```

or

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2['value'] *= 2
```

or

```
df2 = pd.concat([df["id"], df["value"]*2], axis=1)
```